# Can't change the button size using CSS

Tags: html, css

```
.button {
    padding: 0;
    background: chartreuse;
    border: none;
    font-size: 12px;   
}
```

How can I reduce the button size of the Log in button? I even put the padding values to zero but still, the size of the button remains the same. I have attached a screenshot regarding the same.

[image]

Comment: have you tried playing with the properties like `width` and `height` ?

Comment: Please provide your live code! them I will be able to edit it.

Comment: do post your html code also, it's quite unclear whether you have defined 'button' as class in your button tag or not ?

Comment: Please provide your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

for change width of button must change `width:`, `min-width:` or `max-width:` of button

example:

```
.button {
   max-width: 90px !important;
 }
```

Comment: I have even trierd changing the width of the button but nothig happens

Comment: @Ãßhishekßhatt use `!importinat;` for `width` and `max-width`

Answer (score 0):

For using padding to increase the size of the button, you have to give display property either flex or inline-block to the button. You can use width and height property to change the dimension of the button. But this way you weren't able to adjust the properly align text inside the button so my recommendation is to use display flex. Here is the code

```
button{
display:flex;
height:20px;
width:120px;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}
```

Don't forget to include browser fallback for flex property.

Answer (score 0):

Why You have not used height and width? ok now apply this css and change height and width according to your design.

```
button{
 height:80px
 width:80px;
 padding: 0;
 background: chartreuse;
 border: none;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 12px; 
}
```